# Create a dynamic object that implements my custom interface

Tags: c#, dynamic, interface, dynamicobject

I am creating some custom API. What I need is pass some object to the api that have  "static" required propreties and dynamic optional properties.

I have created a dynamic custom object like this:

```
public class MyDynamicEntity : DynamicObject, IMyDynamicEntity
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And my API has this signature:

```
void DoWork(MyDynamicEntity myEntity);
```

Everything "seems" work, but the problem is that the intellisense does not help programmers (that are not me) how to use my API.... Infact to use the api they must write something like this:

```
dynamic myEntity = new MyDynamicEntity();
myEntity.DynamicPropA = ...;
myEntity.DynamicPropB = ...;
...
myEntity.Key = ...;
myEntity.Type = ...;
```

They must declare an object of type `dynamic`, so it is not visible to who use the API the exists two required props: `Key` and`Type`..

Can anyone have a suggestion how to solve my problem?
thanx

PS.: Due to some reasons, I cannot simply create some classes that implements my `IMyDynamicEntity` interface...

Exactly, I must create a mapping between my `MyDynamicEntity` class and a strictly "Azure-bounded" class: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity` (or `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity`). 
But my API must be generic and not specific to a use case. 
Furthermore my API cannot expose a `DynamicTableEntity` (or a `TableEntity` nor a custom class that inherits one of them) otherwise the client that use my API would import Azure DLLs.

I am looking for a solution easy to remember in some moths to me and easy to understand for who must use my API, so I do not need to explain everyone what they have to do with the API.

Comment: `Due to some reasons` What are those reasons?

Comment: This seems like a job for generics. If it's an interface and not a superclass, though, you still need to implement it in your actual class. What exactly is that `DoWork` requirement from?

Comment: I extended my "PS" that explain what are reasons that let me choose dynamic objects as possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split dynamic and non-dynamic properties like this:

```
interface IMyDynamicEntity {
    string Key { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity : IMyDynamicEntity
{        
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public dynamic Properties { get; } = new MyDynamicProperties();

    private class MyDynamicProperties : DynamicObject {

    }
}
```

Then usage becomes:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.Properties.DynamicPropA = ...;
myEntity.Properties.DynamicPropB = ...;                
myEntity.Key = ...;
myEntity.Type = ...;
```

Alternatively, require "required" properties in constructor:

```
public class MyDynamicEntity : DynamicObject, IMyDynamicEntity
{
    public MyDynamicEntity(string key, string type) {
        Key = key;
        Type = type;
    }
    public string Key { get; }
    public string Type { get; }
}
```

Then usage becomes:

```
dynamic myEntity = new MyDynamicEntity(key, type);
myEntity.DynamicPropA = ...;
myEntity.DynamicPropB = ...;
```